# How Do I Launch the Same Activity Into a Separate Window in Android N Multi-Window?

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat

The docs for the Android N Developer Preview 1 indicate that you can use `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCH_ADJACENT` to request that Android launch an activity into a separate window (freeform) or an adjacent pane (split-screen). Google's sample code shows using `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCH_ADJACENT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` to accomplish this.

This works fine, if the activity being started is a different class than the one doing the starting.

So, for example, if you have a `MainActivity` that has the following code to launch a separate instance of itself:

```
  Intent i=
    new Intent(this, MainActivity.class)
      .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCH_ADJACENT |
        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

  startActivity(i);
```

then the result is that `FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCH_ADJACENT` is ignored and the new activity instance goes into the existing window or pane.

If, however, you launch any other activity (e.g., `SecondActivity.class`), then `FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCH_ADJACENT` works as advertised.

What if you want to allow the user to open two spreadsheets, two notepads, or two of whatever-it-is from your app? How can we use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCH_ADJACENT` to launch two instances of the same activity?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the discussion on [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=203201), you also need to blend in `FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK`:

```
  Intent i=
    new Intent(this, MainActivity.class)
      .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCH_ADJACENT |
        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |
        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);

  startActivity(i);
```

Then the two activity instances will be in separate windows/panes/whatever.

[This sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v7.2/MultiWindow/OptIn) demonstrates this for the N Developer Preview 1.

Comment: I believe the referenced issue is not correct; #203404 refers to a defect in `android:minimalSize` (now `android:minimalWidth`).

Comment: @PaulLammertsma: Sorry! I have lots of issues. :-) I have updated the answer with the correct link.

Comment: "Lots of issues," but weeding through b.android.com isn't one! ;)